# Convert step file to 3D pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion, 3d, solidworks

I would like to convert 3D step file views to pdf. There is no such functionality in Solid Works. I would like to show some views to customer that has no special software. How to achieve this in best way?

Answer (score 2):

Solidworks does support 3D PDF. I have use it several times in Solidworks 2016 SP04, so make sure your version is up to date.

Simply import the step model as you normally would, then go to file -> Save As, then at the bottom of the save window click the `Save as type:` dropdown and change the filetype to PDF. Below the dropdown a new checkbox should appear: `Save as 3D PDF`.

Selecting that option will create a 3D PDF as required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Solid Works software but I imagine it has the option to print a project.
You should therefore install [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) which will add a virtual printer to your system. Print your 3D file to the virtual printer and you'll get a PDF file as output.

Comment: I think  you need a PDF Printer which supports 3D PDF files and as far as i'm aware PDF Creator doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

To create 3D PDF's you need a PDF Printer which supports this, I haven't seen a free piece of software to do this, but there may be one.

Try these -

- PDF Maker : http://www.3dpdfmaker.com/en/
- Tetra 4D : https://tetra4d.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think Tetra 4D is the best solution with its softwares:

**Tetra4D Converter** : simple converter to create 3D PDF with a lot of import options, frequently updated

**Tetra4D Enrich** : create advanced interactive 3D PDF

**Tetra4D Automate** : automatically generate 3D PDF with a simple server solution using Enrich teamplates

[Tetra4D official web site](https://tetra4d.com/)

Comment: This reads like ad-copy, are you affiliated with this software?

Answer (score 0):

I use SimLab composer for converting a range of 3d formats, and it'll happily take in STEP, IGES, STL etc in and spit out 3D PDF (U3D) files.

http://www.simlab-soft.com/

I also use Composer for other tasks... but I will say that SimLab's conversions are pretty darn good overall.

I know that SimLab offers converters for sale as well as their higher-order tools.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following workflow:

- Open the STEP file in [FreeCAD](https://www.freecad.org/)
- Select the body with the mouse
- Export it to X3D or to STL
- Open that in [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net/)
- Export it to U3D
- Include the resulting file in a Latex document using the movie/animate package - Compile with PDFlatex/Miktex or whatever

Of course, you could also just open the STEP file with FreeCAD and export as XHTML, this way you can directly open some views on a web browser without needing to go through 3DPDF.